# VSCode: Format on Save and Go To Decl/Def do not work in Remote-SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, clang-format

I am using VSCode 1.47.3, I found that the **Format on Save**, and **Go to Declaration/Go To Definition** do not work in **Remote-SSH**.

Is it because of VSCode does not support them in Remote-SSH, or do I need to configure some of my settings?

Thanks!
CY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to install 'C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing.' plugin for remote-ssh environment as well.